# Grocery Delivery Services in Denmark

Tags: food-and-drink, denmark, services

We are going to stay in a cottage somewhere in Denmark this summer (Southern Denmark, specifically).

As we would like to spend our time relaxing at our place rather than foraging in the nearest supermarket, we are looking for some kind of delivery service for groceries.

We would like to go there by train and bike. Therefore, bringing loads of food for up to two weeks upfront is not really an option. Are there any other options? (Do these delivery services that seem to be appearing everywhere, at least in Germany, also exist in Denmark?)

Answer (score 5):

It depends where you want to deliver goods, at least in case of nemlig.com:

http://www.nemlig.com/om-nemligcom/hvor-leverer-vi.aspx#

Check zip number, they deliver things in Copenhagen area and in some towns on Zealand island. Minimum order is 400 DKR. You can contact their customer service  via telephone number +4570337233 or use chat function under 'Kunde Service' or Customer Service :-)

Comment: Thanks for the note! Unfortunately, for my case, we stay in Southern Denmark.

Comment: Here is exhaustive list: http://www.onlinesupermarked.net/  Please look under "Danske online supermarkeder" - "Danish online supermarkets",  there must be one which delivers goods to your area.